# CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents() returns events which can't be accessed by CalendarApp.getEventById()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am building an Apps Script web app that gets a list of calendar entries from my default calendar, stores the Event ID and then later tries to retrieve that event to do something with it.

The problem I have is that some events retrieved in the list cannot later be retrieved by ID.

Here's some (simplified) code that I'm using.

```
//I first get a list of Events from the default calendar
var eventList = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents()


//I then iterate over the events saving the event ID for later
eventIdList = [];
eventList.forEach(function(event) {eventIdList.push(event.getId());}

...

//Later in the program I need to get the details of that event 
// so I try to retrieve that one Event by its ID
event = CalendarApp.getEventById(eventId); //returns null for some events!
```

There are specific events that consistently return null when I try to retrieve them by ID.  some are formateed exactly like "normal" event IDs that generally work:
`5v2grutu605rvvaqis91fi6u6b_R20180404T210000@google.com`

And Other IDs look nothing like I've been led to expect:
`040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000001022931735E6D3010000000000000000100000000A762C897D92624C8F7D59B232FEEED2`

Are there different kinds of events that need to be retrieved differently by ID?
Are there more formats for the Calendar Event ID that are not well known or documented yet?

Help?

Comment: How are you using an arrow function? That isn't currently supported in apps script...

Comment: Brian, thanks for catching that - I'm extrapolating from my larger code base so didn't copy/paste directly.  Other parts of my code are Javascript functions in the HTML page which DO allow the arrow function so I let that one slip :-)

Comment: The doc specifies"Calling getEventById(iCalId) only returns an event in the default calendar." Are all these events in the same default calendar ? I doubt.

Comment: @Serge, Yes, i saw that.  I am getting the list of events from the default calendar [CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents()] so I believe it's reasonable to expect getEventById() would have access to that same event.  This is exactly why I'm confused by this behaviour.

Comment: I agree it would be reasonable but what if an event appears only because of an invitation and was created somewhere else?  I work a lot with calendars and have never met such an issue.

Comment: Have you inspected the properties of those events that are retrieved? Owner, attendees, location, etc. Determining how those events are different should be very helpful